# What's wrong with this input?

Tags: replacement

[image][image]Can anybody with all my gratitude tell what's wrong with the input in the attached file? why Mathematica doesn't return the answer?

Thanks in advance[Here is the Attached file](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1793711?p_p_auth=eZffkMN3)

Comment: Please edit the question and copy and paste your code directly into the question rather than a random attachment. This makes it easier for everyone to play around with your code. Also, please try to describe what the expected output should be, and what you’re actually getting.

Comment: \[Epsilon]x=\[PartialD]\[Upsilon]/\[PartialD]x   , \[Epsilon]y=\[PartialD]\[Vee]/\[PartialD]y  ,  \[Epsilon]z=\[PartialD]\[Omega]/\[PartialD]z  ,   \[Gamma]xy= \[PartialD]\[Upsilon]/\[PartialD]y + \[PartialD]\[Vee]/\[PartialD]x , \[Gamma]xz= \[PartialD]\[Upsilon]/\[PartialD]z + (\[PartialD]\[Omega]/\[PartialD]x)  , \[Gamma]yz= \[PartialD]\[Vee]/\[PartialD]z + \[PartialD]\[Omega]/\[PartialD]y    Equation 1

\[Upsilon]=2x y^3; \[Vee]=2 x^2 y^2; \[Epsilon]x=\[PartialD]\[Upsilon]/\[PartialD]x; \[Epsilon]y=\[PartialD]\[Vee]/\[PartialD]y
\[Epsilon]x=\[PartialD]\[Upsilon]/\[PartialD]x

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1793711). Problem is use of `\[Vee]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try learning to type with the synatx is better than using the maths tools,

Define

```
u[x_, y_] := 2 x*y^3
v[x_, y_] := 2 x^2*y^2
```

Then,

```
epislonX = D[u[x, y], x]
```

> 2 y^3

and

```
epislony = D[v[x, y], y]
```

> 4 x^2 y

[image]